# Was it Adino or his army that killed eight hundred at one time?

Tags: bible, exegesis

> **[2 Samuel 23:8 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%2023:8&version=KJV)**
>   These be the names of the mighty men whom David had:
>   The Tachmonite that sat in the seat, chief among the captains; the
>   same was Adino the Eznite: he lift up his spear against eight hundred,
>   whom he slew at one time.

I don't understand about warfare in that epoch, but did Adino alone fight and win eight hundred literally or he commanded an army and did that prowess?

Comment: Sure thing!  Just trying to make the title question match with the question body.  ;)

Comment: This question would probably be better on Biblical Hermeneutics.

Answer (score 5):

Considering that the three generals listed each did fantastic things, it would appear that Andino killed 800 by himself.

For more about the other generals, and the men following them you can read this:

[http://www.southernspiritonline.org/inspirational-stories/the-original-band-of-brothers/](http://www.southernspiritonline.org/inspirational-stories/the-original-%E2%80%98band-of-brothers%E2%80%99/)

Answer (score 3):

In Hebrew, there are no numerals, but the letter aleph is inserted to stand for "one hundred." Additionally, the same aleph can be used to represent a clan or a tribe. As such, it is possible that Andino killed 8 clans, and not 800 people.